# How to get a simple Spring Boot app running on WildFly 27?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

There are many tutorials on the internet, but unfortunately they all have one thing in common: they don't work. The initial situation is as follows:

WildFly 27 is freshly installed on a windows machine, a user account is created with add-user.bat, WildFly is started with standalone.bat and the admin console on port :9990 as well as the WildFly start page on port :8080 are accessible.

A simple Spring Boot web project is created.

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>wildfly-hello-world</name>
    <description>wildfly-hello-world</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The MainApplication class looks like this:

```
package com.example.wildflyhelloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WildflyHelloWorldApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WildflyHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WildflyHelloWorldApplication.class);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping
class HelloWorldController {

    @GetMapping
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

After compiling, the war is copied to the deployments folder. And here the journey ends with a series of `NoClassDefFoundError`s - although these packages/classes are provided by spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar under WEB-INF\lib.

Here is an excerpt from the log:

```
org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag in Module "deployment.wildfly-hello-world-1.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.wildfly-hello-world-1.war" from Service Module Loader): javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
```

Does anyone know how to fix these errors, or does anyone have an actual and working Spring Boot example at hand that runs properly on WildFly?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: SpringBoot is, according to [the docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) a way to create "standalone Spring based Applications".  In other words, a server.  Why are you then deploying this into another server?  SpringBoot is designed to remove the need for the application server by embedding it.  Wildfly is a JavaEE server.  It can do more than SpringBoot but for simple REST servers you should be fine without it.  Try the [Spring Quickstart](https://spring.io/quickstart) to get you going.

Comment: Thank you for the link to spring.io. Since I have been working intensively with Spring Boot for many months, have read all the docs on spring.io and have implemented quite some projects, I don't think this will help me any further. I am well aware that WildFly is a JavaEE server, unlike Tomcat. And now I want to run a Spring Boot application on an enterprise server. That is my intention.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0 will not work with WildFly 27. Spring boot targets Jakarta EE 8 dependencies while WildFly 27 is a Jakarta EE 10 container. You'd need to use Spring Boot 3 or WildFly 26.

Comment: Thanks James, that was exactly the problem. Unfortunately you will not read anything about these incompatibilities between Spring Boot and WildFly, whether in the SB docs nor in the WF docs (at least not in these articles you firstly read to get something started). Maybe you wanna create a post, so I can set this question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [release notes](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2022/11/09/WildFly27-Final-Released/) for WildFly 27, it now only supports Jakarta EE 10. Spring Boot 2.x is targets Jakarta EE 8 API's. Spring Boot 3.x was recently released which targets the Jakarta EE 9 API's. You should be able to use Spring Boot 3 with WildFly 27.

As stated in other comments though, [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) is really meant to work as a standalone application/server within itself. While there is support to work in other servers, I don't think that is the goal of what Spring Boot is.